# Vue: calling method on v-if

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on a Vue project started by someone else and don't have a lot of experience with Vue myself.

With this code:

```
<div :class="{ 'results': isResults }">
    <ais-stats v-slot="{ nbHits }">
        <ais-hits
            v-if="nbHits"
            v-slot="{ items }"
            // resultsExist – how is this called?
        >
            <Product v-for="item in items" :key="item.objectID" :product="item" />
        </ais-hits>

        <p v-else class="text-center">
            No results.
        </p>
    </ais-stats>
</div>

data() {
    return {
        isResults: false
    };
},

methods: {
    resultsExist() {
        isResults: true;
    }
}
```

I want to set a class on the parent `div` when `nbHits` returns results (from Vue instant-search).

The code is working fine in terms of displaying results or the no results message. But I don't know what the syntax is for calling the `resultsExist` method.

Comment: You probably want to take a look the `slot` method and see whether they are emitting a data or not. That is my best guess from the available code shown

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `nbHits` is an object
You can use dynamic class binding

```
<div :class="{'className': nbHits }"></div>
```

Comment: Tried that and get: "Property or method "nbHits" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render."